# Python: how to use attribute from differenct class

Tags: python, python-3.x, ccxt

I have some basic class `Trader` in `trader.py`:

```
class Trader(object):
    def __init__(self, exchange_name, api_key, api_secret):
        self.Exchange = Exchange(exchange_name, api_key, api_secret).exchange
```

and a class `Exchange` in `exchange.py`

```
class Exchange(object):
    def __init__(self, name, api_key, api_secret):
        self.name = name
        exchange_id = name
        exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
        self.exchange = exchange_class({
            'apiKey': api_key,
            'secret': api_secret,
            'timeout': 30000,
            'enableRateLimit': True,
        })
```

The above works. So I can use `self.Exchange` inside the Trader class to use functions against the exchange. But it works only because of this line:

```
self.Exchange = Exchange(exchange_name, api_key, api_secret).exchange
```

I don't like the fact I have to put .exchange after it. I'm just a bit playing and learning python. I'm not very experienced in python programming / I'm also not a coin trader, but I liked the [ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual) package.

How can I make this work without needing to putting the `.exchange` behind my Exchange(...) or is this normal behaviour? Or do I have to make my exchange class in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into `__new__()` vs `__init__()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `exchange` is an attribute of an instance of the `Exchange` class, this is normal behavior.

If you want to access `exchange` without needing to put `.exchange` after your `Exchange` object, you might consider doing away with the `Exchange` class entirely—since it seems you only use it to get the instance of the `exchange_class` from ccxt—and writing a function instead.

Here's an example:

```
def get_exchange(exchange_name, api_key, api_secret):
    exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
    return exchange_class({
        'apiKey': api_key,
        'secret': api_secret,
        'timeout': 30000,
        'enableRateLimit': True,
    })

class Trader:
    def __init__(self, exchange_name, api_key, api_secret):
        self.exchange = get_exchange(exchange_name, api_key, api_secret)
```

This way an `exchange` will be accessible directly by instances of `Trader`.

Comment: Thanks I'll use this solution. But when I'll add additional functions/attributes to the exchange and make it a class. Then you would just use the .exchange() like I was doing now?

Comment: @mealesbia at that point, it would be better to wrap all functions of the `exchange` object that you'll use in methods of the `Exchange` class. Then in `Trader.__init__` just set `self.exchange = Exchange(...)`. Basically use your `Exchange` class instead of accessing the `exchange_class` directly from ccxt.

Answer (score 0):

> you need to create an instance if you would like to use an attribute from another class

```
myInstance = Exchange()
print(myInstance.exchange_id) if you would like to print the name
```

> the scope is local you could also declare a variable global before assigning its value if you would like to use it outside the function or class it is created in